# What is the root of a class?

Tags: ruby, class, oop, singleton, theory

A class is an object in Ruby. Then class should have a class that created that class.

```
class Viktor

end

puts Viktor.class.name # => "Class"
```

Okay. It means that `Class` creates my `Viktor` "object-class". Here's the most interesting part.

```
puts Class.class.name # => "Class"

irb(main):020:0> Class === Class.class
=> true
irb(main):021:0> Class === Class.class.class
=> true
```

So `Class` is created by the `Class` itself.

Can anybody explain how come? Is it a singleton? And what or who did create a first `Class`?

Comment: Magic. No, I am not joking. Well, okay, half-joking.

Comment: There is one class that is not an instance of a class: `BasicObject`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland just tried `irb(main):024:0> BasicObject.class # => Class` ruby 2.3.1p112

Comment: Thanks. I confused that with `BasicObject` being the only class that has no ancestors.